# Certificate issues when using Landscape python API.

Tags: application-development, python, landscape

can anyone help me with some certificate issues..? I'm using Landscape, and trying to use the python API, but I get a CA mismatch, but I've downloaded the .pem, and pointed the script to the location of the .pem.. I get a 403, and error: Message: {"message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.", "error": "SignatureDoesNotMatch"}

Trying to do some testing on a LAN without a CA, the script is being run on the server that Landscape is being run on. Here is the contents of my python script, obviously with critical information changed.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import os, json, sys
from landscape_api.base import API, HTTPError

# change these accordingly
uri = "https://placeholder.bla"
key = "VQ6PP8Vxxxxxx971NHRY"
secret = "RZ+IOK0s8+UQkRWfsxxxxxxxxLhSFKDwIf5Df"
ca = "~/api/key.pem"

api = API(uri, key, secret, ca)
try:
    computers = api.get_computers(query="alert:security-upgrades")
except HTTPError, e:
    print ("\nGot server error:\n"
           "Code: %d\n"
           "Message: %s\n") % (e.code, e.message)
    sys.exit(1)

if len(computers) == 0:
   print "No computers have pending security upgrades."
else:
    for computer in computers:
        print "Id:", computer["id"]
        print "Title:", computer["title"]
        print "Hostname:", computer["hostname"]
        print "Last ping:", computer["last_ping_time"]
        print "Memory:", computer["total_memory"]
        if computer["reboot_required_flag"]:
            print "Needs to reboot!"
        print
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your API endpoint URI is *exactly* as shown in the Landscape server. Typically it will end with `/api/` (trailing slash included). And, of course, that the access keys are correct.

Comment: Used the following command to get the cert.. "echo -n | openssl s_client -connect server:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | sudo tee /home/user/api/key.pem"

EDIT: So it was the ending slash.. Wow. I feel stupid. :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using `~/api/key.pem` ? You might need to throw in an `os.path.expanduser` around it, or otherwise provide the full path.

Comment: Changed to the full file path, so /home/user/api/key.pem - No change. :(